# Getting rid of maxpooling layer causes running cuda out memory error pytorch

Tags: python, machine-learning, computer-vision, out-of-memory, pytorch

Video card: gtx1070ti 8Gb, batchsize 64, input image size 128*128.
I had such UNET with resnet152 as encoder which worked pretty fine:

```
class UNetResNet(nn.Module):
 
def __init__(self, encoder_depth, num_classes, num_filters=32, dropout_2d=0.2,
             pretrained=False, is_deconv=False):
    super().__init__()
    self.num_classes = num_classes
    self.dropout_2d = dropout_2d

    if encoder_depth == 34:
        self.encoder = torchvision.models.resnet34(pretrained=pretrained)
        bottom_channel_nr = 512
    elif encoder_depth == 101:
        self.encoder = torchvision.models.resnet101(pretrained=pretrained)
        bottom_channel_nr = 2048
    elif encoder_depth == 152:
        self.encoder = torchvision.models.resnet152(pretrained=pretrained)
        bottom_channel_nr = 2048
     
    else:
        raise NotImplementedError('only 34, 101, 152 version of Resnet are implemented')

    self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)

    self.relu = nn.ReLU(inplace=True)

    self.conv1 = nn.Sequential(self.encoder.conv1,
                               self.encoder.bn1,
                               self.encoder.relu,
                               self.pool) #from that pool layer I would like to get rid off

    self.conv2 = self.encoder.layer1
    self.conv3 = self.encoder.layer2
    self.conv4 = self.encoder.layer3
    self.conv5 = self.encoder.layer4
    self.center = DecoderCenter(bottom_channel_nr, num_filters * 8 *2, num_filters * 8, False)
    
    self.dec5 =  DecoderBlockV(bottom_channel_nr + num_filters * 8, num_filters * 8 * 2, num_filters * 8,   is_deconv)
    self.dec4 = DecoderBlockV(bottom_channel_nr // 2 + num_filters * 8, num_filters * 8 * 2, num_filters * 8, is_deconv)
    self.dec3 = DecoderBlockV(bottom_channel_nr // 4 + num_filters * 8, num_filters * 4 * 2, num_filters * 2, is_deconv)
    self.dec2 = DecoderBlockV(bottom_channel_nr // 8 + num_filters * 2, num_filters * 2 * 2, num_filters * 2 * 2,
                               is_deconv)
    self.dec1 = DecoderBlockV(num_filters * 2 * 2, num_filters * 2 * 2, num_filters, is_deconv)
    self.dec0 = ConvRelu(num_filters, num_filters)
    self.final = nn.Conv2d(num_filters, num_classes, kernel_size=1)

def forward(self, x):
    conv1 = self.conv1(x)
    conv2 = self.conv2(conv1)
    conv3 = self.conv3(conv2)
    conv4 = self.conv4(conv3)
    conv5 = self.conv5(conv4) 
    center = self.center(conv5)
    dec5 = self.dec5(torch.cat([center, conv5], 1))
    dec4 = self.dec4(torch.cat([dec5, conv4], 1))
    dec3 = self.dec3(torch.cat([dec4, conv3], 1))
    dec2 = self.dec2(torch.cat([dec3, conv2], 1))
    dec1 = self.dec1(dec2)
    dec0 = self.dec0(dec1)

    return self.final(F.dropout2d(dec0, p=self.dropout_2d))
# blocks
    class DecoderBlockV(nn.Module):
        def __init__(self, in_channels, middle_channels, out_channels, is_deconv=True):
            super(DecoderBlockV2, self).__init__()
            self.in_channels = in_channels
    
            if is_deconv:
                self.block = nn.Sequential(
                    ConvRelu(in_channels, middle_channels),
                    nn.ConvTranspose2d(middle_channels, out_channels, kernel_size=4, stride=2,
                                       padding=1),
                    nn.BatchNorm2d(out_channels),
                    nn.ReLU(inplace=True)
                    
                )
            else:
                self.block = nn.Sequential(
                    nn.Upsample(scale_factor=2, mode='bilinear'),
                    ConvRelu(in_channels, middle_channels),
                    ConvRelu(middle_channels, out_channels),
                )
    
        def forward(self, x):
            return self.block(x)



class DecoderCenter(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_channels, middle_channels, out_channels, is_deconv=True):
        super(DecoderCenter, self).__init__()
        self.in_channels = in_channels

        
        if is_deconv:
            """
                Paramaters for Deconvolution were chosen to avoid artifacts, following
                link https://distill.pub/2016/deconv-checkerboard/
            """

            self.block = nn.Sequential(
                ConvRelu(in_channels, middle_channels),
                nn.ConvTranspose2d(middle_channels, out_channels, kernel_size=4, stride=2,
                                   padding=1),
        nn.BatchNorm2d(out_channels), 
                nn.ReLU(inplace=True)
            )
        else:
            self.block = nn.Sequential(
                ConvRelu(in_channels, middle_channels),
                ConvRelu(middle_channels, out_channels)
 
            )

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.block(x)
```

Then I edited my class looks to make it work without pooling layer:

```
class UNetResNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, encoder_depth, num_classes, num_filters=32, dropout_2d=0.2,
                 pretrained=False, is_deconv=False):
        super().__init__()
        self.num_classes = num_classes
        self.dropout_2d = dropout_2d

        if encoder_depth == 34:
            self.encoder = torchvision.models.resnet34(pretrained=pretrained)
            bottom_channel_nr = 512
        elif encoder_depth == 101:
            self.encoder = torchvision.models.resnet101(pretrained=pretrained)
            bottom_channel_nr = 2048
        elif encoder_depth == 152:
            self.encoder = torchvision.models.resnet152(pretrained=pretrained)
            bottom_channel_nr = 2048
        else:
            raise NotImplementedError('only 34, 101, 152 version of Resnet are implemented')

        self.relu = nn.ReLU(inplace=True)

        self.input_adjust = nn.Sequential(self.encoder.conv1,
                                          self.encoder.bn1,
                                          self.encoder.relu)

        self.conv1 = self.encoder.layer1
        self.conv2 = self.encoder.layer2
        self.conv3 = self.encoder.layer3
        self.conv4 = self.encoder.layer4

        self.dec4 = DecoderBlockV(bottom_channel_nr, num_filters * 8 * 2, num_filters * 8, is_deconv)
        self.dec3 = DecoderBlockV(bottom_channel_nr // 2 + num_filters * 8, num_filters * 8 * 2, num_filters * 8,    is_deconv)
        self.dec2 = DecoderBlockV(bottom_channel_nr // 4 + num_filters * 8, num_filters * 4 * 2, num_filters * 2,    is_deconv)
        self.dec1 = DecoderBlockV(bottom_channel_nr // 8 + num_filters * 2, num_filters * 2 * 2, num_filters * 2 * 2,is_deconv)
        self.final = nn.Conv2d(num_filters * 2 * 2, num_classes, kernel_size=1)

    def forward(self, x):
        input_adjust = self.input_adjust(x)
        conv1 = self.conv1(input_adjust)
        conv2 = self.conv2(conv1)
        conv3 = self.conv3(conv2)
        center = self.conv4(conv3)
        dec4 = self.dec4(center) #now without centblock
        dec3 = self.dec3(torch.cat([dec4, conv3], 1))
        dec2 = self.dec2(torch.cat([dec3, conv2], 1))
        dec1 = F.dropout2d(self.dec1(torch.cat([dec2, conv1], 1)), p=self.dropout_2d)
        return self.final(dec1)
```

is_deconv - in both cases True. After changing it stop to work with batchsize 64, only with with size of 16 or with batchsize 64 but with resnet16 only - otherwise out of cuda memory. What am I doing wrong?

Full stack of error:

```
~/Desktop/ml/salt/open-solution-salt-identification-master/common_blocks/unet_models.py in forward(self, x)
    418         conv1 = self.conv1(input_adjust)
    419         conv2 = self.conv2(conv1)
--> 420         conv3 = self.conv3(conv2)
    421         center = self.conv4(conv3)
    422         dec4 = self.dec4(center)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in __call__(self, *input, **kwargs)
    355             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    356         else:
--> 357             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    358         for hook in self._forward_hooks.values():
    359             hook_result = hook(self, input, result)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/container.py in forward(self, input)
     65     def forward(self, input):
     66         for module in self._modules.values():
---> 67             input = module(input)
     68         return input
     69 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in __call__(self, *input, **kwargs)
    355             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    356         else:
--> 357             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    358         for hook in self._forward_hooks.values():
    359             hook_result = hook(self, input, result)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torchvision-0.2.0-py3.6.egg/torchvision/models/resnet.py in forward(self, x)
     79 
     80         out = self.conv2(out)
---> 81         out = self.bn2(out)
     82         out = self.relu(out)
```

Comment: You don't have enough memory, that's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you do not have enough memory, as already mentioned in the comments.

To be more specific, the problem lies in the increased size due to the removal of the max pooling, as you already correctly narrowed it down. The point of max pooling - aside from the increased [invariance](https://aboveintelligent.com/ml-cnn-translation-equivariance-and-invariance-da12e8ab7049) of the setting - is to reduce the *image size*, such that it costs you less memory because you need to store less activations for the backpropagation part.

A good answer of what max pooling does might be helpful. My go-to one is the one on [Quora](https://www.quora.com/What-is-max-pooling-in-convolutional-neural-networks).
As you also correctly figured out already is the fact that the batch size also plays a huge role in terms of memory consumption. Generally, [it is also preferred to use smaller batch sizes anyways](https://twitter.com/ylecun/status/989610208497360896?lang=en), as long as you don't have a skyrocketing processing time after.